# Changing url in requests (Python)

Tags: python, python-requests

I got some strange error with requests. Code is:

```
    key = key.replace(" ", "_")
    print(key)
    url = f"https://pl.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/{key}"
    print(url)
    summary = http.get(url)
    summary = summary.json()
    print(summary)
```

The output from prints:

```
A

https://pl.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/A


{'type': 'https://mediawiki.org/wiki/HyperSwitch/errors/bad_request', 'method': 'get', 'detail': 'title-invalid-characters', 'uri': '/pl.wikipedia.org/v1/page/summary/A%0A'}
```

The site returns an error with `uri` that is different from the `url` variable. Why? Anyway, I cannot access it. And I see `A` is changing to `A%0A.`

Comment: What's the content of key at the beginning?

Comment: It is user-defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you see an empty line in the output (2nd line) after the A. That is the problem. A line feed is there at the end of A.. (A\n). You have to remove the \n.

Use `key.strip()`. This will remove all leading and trailing whitespace.

And URL encoding for LF - line feed (\n) is %0A. That's why your URL changed to A + %0A.